# How to combine a list of services from different array elements into one list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array of data .
Here is a photo of the model:
[image]

This model has an array of services.
I want to use a request to combine all services from all elements and have one list.

I tried to do like this but it doesn't work. Maybe someone knows how to do it??
My example :

```html
  List<PriceServicesModel> get selectedServices {
    List<PriceServicesModel> list = [];
    for (var element in multiServicesModel) {
      for (var services in element.services) {
        list = [...list, services];
        print(list);
      }
      return list;
    }
    return list;
  }
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the `list` at the end of function.

```
List<PriceServicesModel> get selectedServices {
    final List<PriceServicesModel> list = [];
    for (var element in multiServicesModel) {
      list = list.addAll(element.services);
      //return list; //This line should be removed
    }
    return list;
  }
```

I made some optimisations here.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a list with every iteration, just use list.add() instead. And also remove the first return, so it doesn't return after the first loop.

```
List<PriceServicesModel> get selectedServices {
    List<PriceServicesModel> list = [];
    for (var element in multiServicesModel) {
      for (var services in element.services) {
        list.add(services);
      }
    }
    return list;
  }
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: everything is ok, I made a mistake due to inattention